# Why function file returns empty array?

Tags: php, arrays, file

```
Done
<?php
    define('FILE_NAME', 'list.dat');
    define('MAX_BREAK', 30);

    function write($file, $ip, $time)
    {
        fwrite($file, $ip . '|' . $time . "\n");
    }

    $new_ip = /*$REMOTE_ADDR*/ $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $file = fopen(FILE_NAME, 'w+');
    flock($file, LOCK_EX | LOCK_SH);

    $array = file(FILE_NAME, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    $contains = false;
    foreach ($array as $record)
    {
        $values = explode('|', $record);
        $ip = $values[0];
        $time = $values[1];
        if ($ip == $new_ip)
        {
            $time = time();
            $contains = true;
        }
        if (time() - $time < MAX_BREAK)
            write($file, $ip, $time);
    }
    if (!$contains)
        write($file, $new_ip, time());

    flock($file, LOCK_UN);
    fclose($file);
?>
```

$array is empty, but it shouldn't because file contains one line.
Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `list.dat` is empty.

`fopen with w+`

> 'w+' Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and truncate the file to zero length. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.

Answer (score 1):

If the file command is returning false, it means file() failed. I think it might be failing because you already have it locked with your flock() call.  The file() function does not need to be preceded by an fopen().

Comment: He is calling `fopen()` to write to the file.

Answer (score 1):

Using `flock()` you aquire an exclusive lock on the file and after that you want to read it. That doesn't work. A shared lock will probably be enough (no one can alter the file while it's locked).

```
flock($file, LOCK_EX | LOCK_SH);
```

becomes

```
flock($file, LOCK_SH);
```